# scanf("%3s", str) with only 1 input character in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   char str[3];
   scanf("%3s", str);
   return 0;
}
```

What is the content of str[2] if I enter only one character? Is this undefined behaviour or will all remaining characters be fillt with '\0'? I do only care about the first three charaters. Even the \0 terminator is irrelivant to me because I do not want to use this array as a String.

I tried this and the remaining characters were all '\0' but this could be compiler specific.

Comment: You are mixing an array of characters with an array of pointers. You are passing the address of your array of pointers to `scanf`. That should trigger some compiler warning about parameter type mismatch as you must pass a `char*` while you pass a `char**`. When you check `str[2]` you are not looking where you think you look.

Comment: Please clarify whether or not you meant this to be an array of pointers, or if the `*` is just a typo.

Comment: `%s` will write up to 3 non-whitespace characters followed by one null terminator character. Assuming you meant `char str[3];` rather than `char* str[3];`, then note that there would be undefined behavior if the `scanf` call read 3 non-whitespace characters, because writing the null terminator character would result in a buffer overrun condition.

Comment: The char* was just a typo and should be char. I will anjust the question.

Comment: To answer your question, the value of `str[2]` will be indeterminate.

Comment: @Gerhardh I used the VSCode debugger but in generell it should also be possible to check the content with prinf("str[0]:%d, str[1]:%d, str[2]:%d\n", (int)str[0], (int)str[1], (int)str[2])

Comment: After changing the type of your array, my comment became obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the content of str[2] if I enter only one character?

The content would be indeterminate, since this is is a local array which was never initialized. `scanf` (family) used with `%3s` only guarantees that up to 3 characters are read - but if the user types for example a letter then a whitespace character, `scanf` will stop there and only read the one character entered.

It is also appending a null terminator character after the input, so in case the user types exactly 3 characters and then hit enter, `scanf` will write the null terminator out of bounds.

You can try this yourself with this little program that prints the binary contents of the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char str[4]={1,2,3,4};
  scanf("%3s", str);
  printf("%.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X", str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3]);
}
```

Here I changed the size to 4 and  initialized the array for illustration purposes.

- Input: `A <enter>`
  Output: `41 00 03 04`

  `41` being the ASCII value of `'A'`, `00` being the null terminator appended and `03 04` being the contents that happened to be in the memory since before. If this would have been an uninitialized local array, those values could have been "garbage". As we can see, `scanf` does *not* "zero pad" the remaining parts of the array (like `strncpy` would do, for example).
- Input: `ABC <enter>`
  Output: `41 42 43 00`

  `41 42 43` are the letters and `00` is the appended null terminator. Had this been an array with size 3, it would have been out of bounds. `scanf` has no clue how big the array is, so I would have lied to `scanf` if I used `%3s` and passed it a `char [3]` array, saying "hey you can store 3 characters + null termination here", even though there wouldn't be any room left.

Comment: (The array has its address taken so it is not explicitly UB. It could not "have been declared with `register`". Furthermore character types may not hold trap representations.)

Comment: "with %3s only guarantees that up to 3 characters are read" ---> more like "with %3s only guarantees that up to 3 non-white-space characters are read"

Answer (score 1):

The rule for processing an `s` conversion, in C 2018 7.21.6.2, says:

> … the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character, which will be added automatically…

This tells us that, if you enter one (non-white-space) character (and presumably follow it with a white-space character or some end-of-input indication), that the character will be put into `str` (at `str[0]`) and a null character will be put into `str` after it.

The standard does not say anything is written to any elements of `str` after those.

Note that `%3s` allows up to three characters to be read, in which case you need four elements in `str` so that it can hold the three characters and the terminating null character.

Answer (score 0):

C strings are char arrays. The string is terminated with the null terminating character.

To store 3 characters + null terminating character you need 4 elements char array.

Your `scanf` will invoke undefined behaviour if the user enters `3` or more chars.

> What is the content of `str[2]` if I enter only one character? Is this
> undefined behaviour or will all remaining characters be fillt with
> '\0'?

As your variable has **automatic storage duration** the value `str[2]` is not determinable (it can be anything).

If `str` array has **static storage duration** (ie is defined inside the function with the `static` attribute or is global) then it will have value of `0` (as not initialized static storage duration objects are zeroed before call to the `main` functions is done.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the content of `str[2]` if I enter only one character?

The content of `str[2]` is indeterminant.

---

**Also a potential bug**

The width in `"%3s"` is 1 too high.

```
char str[3];
scanf("%3s", str);
```

Tip, avoid coding the wrong *width* with `%s`.

```
#define GET_WORD_N 256
#define str(token) #token
#define xstr(token) str(token)

char* get_word(void) {
  static char buf[GET_WORD_N + 1];
  if (scanf("%" xstr(GET_WORD_N) "%s", buf) == 1) {
    return buf;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```